# Ubuntu boots into emergency mode. ^D and other recovery options fail. How can I fix it?

Tags: boot, filesystem, fstab, fsck

From similar questions, I thought it would be useful to run `blkid` and `cat etc/fstab` for your reference to help me figure out what is going on.

`blkid` has only 1 entry: `/dev/sda1` which is my HDD with OS, while
`/etc/fstab` has the same listed with its `UUID=dd243628-27f1-4448-9480-c9e336997d0`

[image: I took a screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Problem was in the /etc/fstab where I had added a USB drive entry prior to the previous shutdown before being unable to boot. (See last entry on the screenshot for sdb1)

This entry happened when I was trying to mount my USB drive.

Solution? I just commented out that entry using 'sudo nano /etc/fstab' and hard rebooted the PC.

The MF booted right up into my regular Lubuntu desktop.

Comment: Please, mind your language and stop writing things such as "MF" in your answers... Thank you.

Comment: what's wrong with writing it- MF?

Comment: @AfroFX Can you please let us know the full form of MF such that there won't be any confusion?

Comment: It is what it appears to be MF - a MainFrame